# How to customize a paragraph with css in RMarkdown

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

```
---
title: "My study"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---
```

I used the code below to control the text format of my entire document

```
<style type="text/css">
  body{
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: Garamond;
  line-height:1.8;
  
}
</style>
```

I want now to customize certain paragraphes or subtitles

```
## SUBTITLE 1 (to color in blue)
```

.

```
## SUBTITLE 2 (to color in blue)
```

.

```
 { in italic and colored in brown and line-height=1
    My paragraph text My paragraph text My paragraph text My paragraph text My paragraph text
    My paragraph text My paragraph text My paragraph text My paragraph text My paragraph text
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Level 2 headings are rendered as `h2` html elements. To change the color of all of these headings you could do the following, which will change all `## {insert heading}` to have a blue font.

```
h2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

To change the color of certain headings, you can create them using html tags and give them a class. Then change the style of the class in the CSS.

HTML:

```
<h2 class="purple-heading">Some heading</h2>
```

CSS:

```
.purple-heading {
  color: purple;
}
```

To style certain paragraphs, wrap them in a `<p>` tag and give them a class. Then style the class in CSS.

HTML:

```
<p class="large-p">A long and very large paragraph.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.large-p {
  font-size: 96px;
}
```

Overall markdown file:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

<style type="text/css">
  body{
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: Garamond;
  line-height:1.8;
  }
  
  h2 {
    color: blue;
  }
  .purple-heading {
    color: purple;
  }
  
  .large-p {
    font-size: 96px;
  }
</style>

## H2
<h2 class="purple-heading">Some heading</h2>
some un-styled text

<p class="large-p">A long and very large paragraph.</p>
````

If you have more than a few things to style (and maybe even if you don't) I recommend separating the html/markdown from the CSS. You can create a .css file and change the YAML header as follows:

```
---
title: "test"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: your_path.css
---
```